# How to print numbers horizontally?

Tags: linux, bash

I would like to print something as 5,4,3,2,1.

This is my program, but it prints the numbers vertically.

```
numbers=5
i=1
while [ "$i" -le "$numbers" ]
do
echo “$i”
i=$(( $i + 1 ))
done
```

Do you have any solution that could help me?

Comment: `echo '5,4,3,2,1'` — this is the simplest answer that can work, as the question is stated.

Comment: `echo` has a `-n` option

Comment: @HalosGhost no it's not. Asking for help on shell scripting is explicitly [_on_ topic](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Whatever made you think it's not? What we don't like is people asking us to write their code for them when they haven't put any effort into it. Questions about shell scripting make up a large percentage of what we deal with here.

Comment: @terdon, you are correct; I don't know what led me to that conclusion; I was just about to remove my earlier comment, but it appears it has already been removed. Thank you!

Comment: @HalosGhost yes, I deleted it to avoid confusion. I also cleared up the rest of our conversation to keep the question tidy. And don't worry about it, we all get confused about the scope of the various SE sites :).

Answer (score 4):

There are many ways to do this, here are some:

1. [Use `seq`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/145252/22222) as @Gnouc suggested.
2. Use brace expansion and convert spaces to commas:

   ```
   $ echo {5..1} | sed 's/ /,/g' 
   5,4,3,2,1
   ```
3. Use your script but change decrement the counter instead of incrementing it and change `echo` to `echo -n` (this will work for bash's builtin `echo` but not for all `echo` implementations):

   ```
   i=5
   while [ "$i" -gt 1 ]
   do
       echo -n "$i,"
       let i--
   done
   echo "$i"
   ```
4. Use `printf` instead:

   ```
   i=5
   while [ "$i" -gt 1 ]
   do
       printf "%s," "$i"
       let i--
   done
   printf "%s\n" "$i"
   ```
5. Use a variable:

   ```
   i=5
   v=5
   while [ "$i" -gt 1 ]
   do
       let i--;
       v=$v,$i
   done
   echo $v
   ```

Answer (score 3):

With `seq`, you can do:

```
$ seq -s, 5 -1 1
5,4,3,2,1
```

And a `perl` solution can be portable:

```
$ perl -e 'print join ",", reverse 1..5'
```